# Ubuntu Read-only file system for non system files

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

I've been trying to use Ubuntu for the first time and I was trying to edit php files using `sublimetext` and when I try to save I get "Read-only file system" while these files are not system file and they are on this path

```
/media/username/01CF7828B81BAC40/xampp/htdocs
```

This user is an administrator. I tried to change permissions through the properties dialog box to read and write but it shows "preparing" option and nothings changes. So how can I grant read and write permissions for any folder to create/  delete sub folders and edit / create / delete files within?

[The problem is not related to htdocs folder only it's related to all files and folders in the partition which is sda5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Read-only file system" means "Read-only file system".  Given the path, it's probably a DVD-ROM or CD-ROM which is why it's non-writeable.  Changing permissions won't help.

If you just want to save, try saving to a different location (your home directory `~/` or /tmp).

If you're sure that you can write to this path, try running `mount` to see if it was mounted read-only.  If you are `root` or have `sudo` permissions you can try to remount the filesystem with read-write permissions, then your change permissions should work.

Be sure you don't hibernate Windows before using Ubuntu so you can write to NTFS partitions.

Comment: This is volume D on windows just a partition with files on my PC. And the problem is I;m new to Linux and don't know how to mount but yes I have 
   sudo    permissions hope you can help me with that. Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the output of `mount`?

Comment: would you please help me with the mount command for this partition? /media/username/01CF7828B81BAC40/

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing the output of the mount command.  You can look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions if you don't want to share it.

Comment: I know I asked how to unmount and mount using the terminal as I don't u the command it's not about sharing the result. If the file system matters the D partition is NTFS

Comment: It's my bad but I didn't know about it. I was hibernating windows and hibernation files are stored on D and as I understood windows shouldn't be hibernated so Ububtu can write to NTFS partitions. I restarted windows and logged into Ubuntu and now I can write to it. Thanks

Comment: Ah, glad you figured out the issue.

Comment: Just to add to this answer - I've found often Windows 10 shutdown is actually a form of hibernation and can leave a lock-file on a shared NTFS drive. `shutdown\p` from windows seems to do a full shutdown.